# New lizard lost tail 2 times already, worried about his/her safety

Tags: health, leopard-geckos

So recently, our family bought 2 more leopard geckos for the current 2 ones we already had... My sister's gecko is "supposedly" a girl, and her new young girl/boy got along nicely. They separated but soon started sleeping together more often then not.

My lizard is a bit older than my sister's. We believe he's a large fat-tail male.

I placed my new baby in the cage, and Hammy bit him on the first night right in the face, I immediately separated them, but later on, they started "Getting Along" and slept in the same hide for a couple days. About 3 days after buying "Chicki," as we called him, he lost half his tail.

I tried figuring out what caused it, I have a healthy semi-humid environment, I feed them often, give them a large clean water-bowl, and I block out very bright lights, all the crazy stuff. Then he still lost his tail, so I guessed Hammy ate it (I couldn't find it anywhere).

A few days later, they are sleeping in the same hide again. Finally just yesterday, he lost a bit more of his tail. He's got maybe 3/4ths of a centimeter left.

I'm worried that Hammy is hurting him at night, because I never see them fight during the day, and in fact, if I go to grab them both out, Hammy actually seems to "protect" him, and the two huddle up together sometimes, but at night, they go to opposite hides.

Does anyone know what I should do? Hammy hasn't hurt him any way else.

**Please do keep in mind, we named Chicki, well, Chicki, because hes a bit of a chicken. Everything scares him and makes him stick his tail in the air and wag it like a dog. Its' possible he just dropped the tail and Hammy ate it, as Hammy is normally never violent.**

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like he lost his tail due to stress. According to https://funwithlife.org/leopard-gecko/hideout/, leopard geckos aren't particularly social creatures and housing them together often times won't work. For sure, though, you'll need different hides for each gecko (ideally two: one warm hide and one cool hide).

Personally, I'd separate them into different vivariums.

Comment: I wound up taping a cardboard wall, and getting another wooden hide, they fight over the wood hide we have, even though we have other hides..

I just really needed to get chicki out of danger, so I separated them.